# CSS3 Prism animation malfunction

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions

I am working on an experimental project on CSS3, 3D animations in -webkit- browsers, all things works fine except the final placement of my 3sided prism.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/HomamGhassemy/GTvZp/) is the fiddle for the code.
the calendar view port most fit in red border after animation.

this id my css that genrates the animation:

```
.flipbox-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.flipbox-container .flipwrap {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-57px) rotateY(0deg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
}
.flipbox-container .date-box {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
}
.flipbox-container .date-box:first-child {
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(57px);
}
.flipbox-container .date-box:nth-child(2) {
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(57px);
}
.flipbox-container .date-box:last-child {
    background: #aaa;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(57px);
}
.flipbox-container .flipwrap.f1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(57px) rotateY(-120deg);
}
.flipbox-container .flipwrap.f2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-133px) rotateY(-240deg);
```

**please note that it should be seen in a -webkit- browser!**

Answer (score 1):

The correct CSS should be:

```
/*calendar*/
 .date-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.date-box>div {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.date-box>.left {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.date-box>.right {
    float: right;
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
}
.date {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*rotative*/
 .flipbox-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.flipbox-container .flipwrap {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-57px) rotateY(0deg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
}
.flipbox-container .date-box {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
}
.flipbox-container .date-box:first-child {
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(57px);
}
.flipbox-container .date-box:nth-child(2) {
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(57px);
}
.flipbox-container .date-box:last-child {
    background: #aaa;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(57px);
}
.flipbox-container .flipwrap.f1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-57px) rotateY(-120deg);
}
.flipbox-container .flipwrap.f2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-57px) rotateY(-240deg);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTvZp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should consider:

- The transform-origin of the ".flipbox-container .flipwrap" class should be "center center"
- You are also changing the translateZ property during animation. The prism only stays inside the red box, when the translateZ property is <=-57. The f1 class has a translateZ property of 57px and will not stay inside the red box.